# $\frac{1-\sqrt{8x-3}}x\ge4$ – no solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{8x-3}}x\ge4$$
The book I'm reading says there is no solution to this, but I could not understand what I was trying to solve.

Comment: the function on the left is decreasing, so the highest value it obtains is at $x = \frac{3}{8}$ (so that the numerator is defined), which yields $\frac{8}{3} < 4$.

Answer (score 1):

First, we multiply with $x$

$$1-\sqrt{8x-3}\ge 4x$$

Remark : $x$ must be positive, otherwise we cannot calculate $\sqrt{8x-3}$.

Next step : Subtract 1

$$-\sqrt{8x-3}\ge 4x-1$$

Multiplying with $(-1)$ gives

$$\sqrt{8x-3}\le 1-4x$$

A real square root of $8x-3$ only exists, is $x\ge \frac{3}{8}$ , but this implies $-x\le-\frac{3}{8}$ , hence $-4x\le -\frac{3}{2}$ , so finally $1-4x\le - \frac{1}{2}$

So, the right side must be negative, but the square root is per convention non-negative.

Therefore the inequality has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would explain it this way:

First, the domain of the inequation is defined by $\; x> \frac 38$. On this  domain hence $x>0$, so we can multiply both sides by $x$, getting
$$1-\sqrt{8x-3}\ge 4x\iff\sqrt{8x-3}\le 1-4x\iff\begin{cases}8x-3\le (1-4x)^2\\ \textbf{and}\\1-4x\ge 0.\end{cases}$$
So any solution has to be $\le \frac14$, a condition incompatible with the domain of the inequation.